# Python 3.4: Trying to .rjust an entire loop of numbers

Tags: python, loops, numbers

I've been working working on this one problem for a few days now (off and on).  I know I need to create a "spacing" loop outside the interior loop, but I have no idea how to implement it.  I've done a lot of trial and error and feel like I am pretty close.

Please keep in mind this is my first programming class ever (for any language).

I am trying to edit my code to look like (sorry I am having a hard time trying to get the format correct, basically the same as the list below but `.rjust(10)`:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
      0 1 2 3 4 5 6
        0 1 2 3 4 5
          0 1 2 3 4
            0 1 2 3
              0 1 2
                0 1
                  0
```

I have been able to make it look like:

```
0123456789
012345678
01234567
0123456
012345
01234
0123
012
01
0
```

Basically I need to .rjust every row, but am having issues making it work.  I know if I used `print(str(0123456789).rjust(10))` it would give me what I am looking for (for the first row), but I need to implement this inside a loop.

Here is the code I have thus far:

```
for i in range(10,0,-1):
  print()
  print()
  for j in range(i):
    stringnum=str(j)
    print(stringnum,end="")
```

Comment: Your formatting is quite confusing - could you please make effort to adjust the formatting so that we understand what you are expecting.

Answer (score 3):

Using [format-specification-mini-language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
for i in range(10,-1,-1):
    print("{:>10}".format("".join(map(str,range(i)))))

0123456789
 012345678
  01234567
   0123456
    012345
     01234
      0123
       012
        01
         0
```

If you want spacing you must double the right align `>`:

```
for i in range(10,-1,-1):
    print("{:>19}\n".format(" ".join(map(str,range(i)))))

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

      0 1 2 3 4 5 6

        0 1 2 3 4 5

          0 1 2 3 4

            0 1 2 3

              0 1 2

                0 1

                  0
```

For spacing between the columns only remove the newline:

```
for i in range(10,-1,-1):
    print("{:>19}".format(" ".join(map(str,range(i)))))

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
      0 1 2 3 4 5 6
        0 1 2 3 4 5
          0 1 2 3 4
            0 1 2 3
              0 1 2
                0 1
                  0
```

Answer (score 1):

here it is using `rjust`:

```
>>> for x in range(10,-1,-1):
...     print("".join(map(str,range(x))).rjust(10))
... 
0123456789
 012345678
  01234567
   0123456
    012345
     01234
      0123
       012
        01
         0
```

in the above code, i am first converting all `integer` to `string`  then  i have used `join` to join the list together to form a string. 
`rjust` return the string left justified in a string of length width.

A space between integers, you just need to add space in `join` function and rjust value will be 19:

```
>>> for x in range(10,-1,-1):
...     print(" ".join(map(str,range(x))).rjust(19))
... 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
      0 1 2 3 4 5 6
        0 1 2 3 4 5
          0 1 2 3 4
            0 1 2 3
              0 1 2
                0 1
                  0
```

Comment: +1, but this would be better with some explanation. (The reason he can't use `rjust` in his original code is because he's printing out each character separately, and you can only call `rjust` on a string, so your code joins all the characters together first, then calls `rjust` on that, then prints it.)